# Как прикрепить макрос к файлу

Tags: excel, vba, макросы

В Excel документе есть макрос на vba.
По копировании документа на флешку, макрос остаётся на ПК.

Как прикрепить его к файлу, что бы при перемещении, копировании он всегда был с файлом?

Answer (score 1):

От вариантов теоретических и вряд ли возможных до более реальных.

=== На компьютере установлена программа, отслеживающая копирование и удаляющая запретный для копирования макрос. Пора менять гражданство и уходить в подполье - за Вами неусыпно следят :)

=== Файл на флешку сохраняется с расширением *.xlsx*. Mакросы там не живут. Это насколько нужно быть "не в себе", чтобы файл перед копированием открыть и сохранить с другим расширением? Разновидность: копирование происходит не *Copy/Paste*, а программой, которая делает свое черное дело.

Более вероятные.

Открываем файл, нажимаем *Alt+F8* (вызов окна макросов). В списке - перечень макросов с указанием места, где они прописаны. Для активной книги отображается только имя, без указания места расположения. Под перечем - выпадающий список, в котором можно выбрать расположение макросов. Большая вероятность того, что **нужный файл находится не в копируемой книге**.

**===** Процедуры, предназначенные для работы во многих файлах, размещают в скрытой книге макросов. *Alt+F11* - вход в редактор VBA. Слева обычно отображается окно проектов (*Prioject-VBAPrioject*). Если его нет - *Ctrl+R*. Открыть *VBAPrioject (PERSONAL.XLSB)-Modules*, в одном из модулей (их может быть несколько) найти нужный макрос, копировать его (можно в текстовый файл) и вставить код  в личную книгу макросов другого компьютера.  Еще макрос может быть найден в модуле *ЭтаКнига* или (маловероятно, но возможно) в модуле листа.

Путь к личной книге макросов:

```
 C:\Users\имя_пользователя\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART\
```

**===** То, что нужно, не просто макрос - надстройка. Файл с расширением *.xlam* находится или в папке надстроек, или в любом другом месте, куда прописан путь. Где искать?

*Файл-Параметры-Надстройки*, внизу окна в выпадающем списке обычно по умолчаию выбрано *Надстройки Excel* (если нет, выбрать этот пункт), нажать кнопку *Перейти*. откроется окно с перечнем доступных надстроек. Те, которые отмечены галками - рабочие. Если нажать кнопку *Обзор*, откроется папка с надстройками, которая находится по пути:

```
C:\Users\имя_пользователя\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns\
```

Копировать нужный файл с расширением *.xlam* и вставить в нужное место другого компьютера. Надстройку допустимо размещать в любой папке: в том же окне надстроек по кнопке *Обзор* найти файл, выделить его, нажать *Открыть* - *Excel* запомнит путь. Конечно, правильнее надстройку сохранять там, где положено. В окне надстроек проверить, подключена ли надстройка.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно зайти в редактор VBA, записать в новый модуль текст макроса и сохранить для книги.

Подробности здесь:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/office/ee814737(v=office.14).aspx